# Get picklist metadata/values

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilesdk

For my iOS App I need to know which values, from a picklist, are possible for the user to select, to only insert the possible ones. 
How can I do this with the mobileSDK for iOS? I tried the requestForDescribe:

```swift
let request: RestRequest = RestClient.shared.requestForDescribe(withObjectType: "Contact")
```

This works, but it is highly inefficient, because I get all data from all the fields. If I try this:

```swift
let request: RestRequest = RestClient.shared.requestForDescribe(withObjectType: "Contact/Z_Key_Opinion_Leader__c")
```

Then I get an error: "Provided external ID field does not exist or is not accessible: Z_Key_Opinion_Leader__c"

Comment: `Highly inefficient` is a bit of a label. All SDK does is wrap the APIs available. Describe api provides all fields (and all picklist values). AFAIC there is no API to return just that one set of fields. If you're keen, you can write your own APEX REST api and discard the lot of other data on the server-side. In practice, however, you may find later on that you also need other values, too...

Comment: Thats sad, but thanks for the answer.